# Application does not take parameters

Tags: scala

For those scala experts out there I am currently writing code for my university coursework and the compiler has thrown an error whereby I am not sure how to resolve.

The following code should simply invoke a menu option:

```
 def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
   actionMap.get(option) match {
    case Some(f) => f()
     case None =>
      println("ERROR: Please enter an option between 1-8")
      true
   }
}
```

The compiler does not like this line:

```
case Some(f) => f()
```

and more specifically it does not like

```
=> f()
```

I am completely new to functional programming and scala therefore, any tips or clue would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: How does your `actionMap` look like

Comment: What is the compiler error ? Show me your actionMap

Comment: `val actionMap = Map[Int, Boolean](1 -> handleOne, 2 -> handleTwo, 3 -> handleThree, 4 -> handleFour, 5 -> handleFive, 6 -> handleSix, 7 -> handleSeven, 8 -> handleEight)`

Comment: I hope the `actionMap` helps.

Comment: Did you try `f` without brackets? In your case, `f`is a boolean not a function returning a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

As `actionMap` is of type `Map[Int, Boolean]`. Following code works.

```
def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
   actionMap.get(option) match {
    case Some(value) => value 
     case None =>
      println("ERROR: Please enter an option between 1-8")
      true
   }
}
```

Parenthesis is for function application. So `f()` should be used only if `f` is a function.

`actionMap.get(someIntValue)` will return option of Boolean and you can pattern match on the option to extract the boolean value. In your code snippet, you are trying to apply the boolean value which is not allowed as it is not a function but a value.

For example if you actionMap were to be something like below then you earlier code is valid

```
val actionMap = Map(1 -> { () -> true}, 2 -> { () -> false})

def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
   actionMap.get(option) match {
    case Some(f) => f() //now f() is valid.
     case None =>
      println("ERROR: Please enter an option between 1-8")
      true
   }
}
```

Comment: I got a ClassNotFoundException. I there any way I can allow you to look at my code without posting on stack overflow.

Comment: Not sure how you can find it but I have created an account with pastebin and my paste is called Coursework429764830, let my know if you find it.

Comment: Thank you for all your help

Comment: @PatrickLafferty ... the code compiles ... What is the problem with the code

Comment: You are right!! I have just copied the code into another project and it ran. But the output was: `The most recent price for each stock - List(6, 6, 8, 3, 1, 9, 1, 6, 0)
Please enter a specify stock to examine - You should type SK followed by the required stock number >` and the output should be the menu. I.e.

Comment: `def readOption: Int = {
    println(
      """|Please select an option from 1-7:
        |1 - Get current (most recent) price for each stock
        |2 - Get the highest and lowest prices from the specified 30-day period
        |3 - Calculate the mean price over the specified 30-day period
        |4 - Calculate the stock price that has increased the most in the last day of the period
        |5 - Compare the value of two stocks - requires two values to be inputted` and so on